# How to do multiple operations in FFMPEG .BAT file

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, m3u8, ffmpeg-php

BAT File.

cd c:/ffmpeg/bin

```
ffmpeg.exe  -i "https://av.livestreamlive.xyz/hls/krt.m3u8" -c:v copy -c:a copy -preset veryslow -pix_fmt yuv420p -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/azad
ffmpeg.exe -i "https://av.livestreamlive.xyz/hls/krt.m3u8" -c:v copy -c:a copy -preset veryslow -pix_fmt yuv420p -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/azad1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start each command with 'start "" /d', this should open a new command window for each thread.

```
start "" /d ffmpeg.exe  -i "https://..." -c:v copy -c:a copy -preset veryslow -pix_fmt yuv420p -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/azad
start "" /d ffmpeg.exe -i "https://..." -c:v copy -c:a copy -preset veryslow -pix_fmt yuv420p -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/azad1
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm getting it. I am using windows 11.

Comment: start "" start "" When I do it this way, the windows are constantly multiplying.